# How do I factory reset Kobo Touch after failed system update?

Tags: ebook, touch

I have a Kobo touch belonging to a friend, it locks up during startup after a system update. How do I factory reset this device? I've scoured the internet for nearly an hour now and haven't found anything helpful. The only site I found that had instructions said to hold the power button down for 15 seconds. I held it for 30 and nothing happened. Additionally, this model has a sliding power button. Is there anything I can do to restore this pathetic device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to try the instructions from factory-reset.com, I've always found the instructions accurate.

> 1.Hold the power button down for about 15 seconds to make sure the device is off.
>
> 2.Hold down the home button and power the device on while keeping it held down. This should force a factory reset.
>
> 3.Set the device up again using the Kobo desktop application as per the device instructions.

http://factory-reset.com/wiki/Touch

Comment: Hello, unfortunately the device refuses to switch off. Sometimes it resets and restarts, but most of the time it does nothing. What can I do to force the thing to switch off?

Comment: @DavidA.Moody Have you tried the paperclip reset? There should be a small hole on the back near the bottom of the device.

http://merch.kobobooks.com/userguides/en/touch_user_guide_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks, got it now, successfully restored to factory specs :-)